# Groovy 3 on Java 10 (Module-Info)

Tags: java, maven, groovy, java-module, java-10

I'm currently trying to upgrade my Maven project to Java 10 but I'm having issues with the new module system.

One of my systems requires groovy for runtime code execution, so I depend on groovy-all (Version 3.0.0-alpha1).

When compiling however, I receive the following error (which results in a build failure):

`module-info.java:[19,20] module not found: groovy.all`

IntelliJ doesn't seem to have an issue with groovy.all while editing my module-info file. (However it seems to have issues with Lombok now?)

I recently came across [this documentation](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compilejava_code_task_to_produce_a_module) for gradle which apparently could help fix my issue, however I'm using maven and right now I'm not sure where classpath.asPath comes from.

Comment: This looks like a question better asked on the groovy-users mailing list